# Not able to authenticate custom user model in Django

Tags: django, authentication, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I created an `Custom User model in Django` and you see my `models.py` below.

```
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
from django.conf import settings
from uuidfield import UUIDField

class User(AbstractUser, Mixin):
    objects = HiddenUserManager()
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    # REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email', 'password']
    api_token = UUIDField(auto=True)
    token_created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('email', )  # must have unique email!
        app_label = 'portal'

    def api_token_reset(self):
        self.api_token = UUIDField(auto=True)
```

I also changed my `settings.py` file and added this line:

`AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'portal.User'` portal is the name of my app.

I have created two `superusers` using the `portal.user model` as you can see in the below image:
[image]

The problem is when I enter my `username and password` in my index login page, it is not able to authenticate me. After creating models I have performed all the `migrations`. Why the the login page is not able to authenticate me?

if I comment out my `customer user model` and remove this line `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'portal.User'`, then my login page is able to authenticate me. Any idea where I am going wrong?

My login view looks something like this :

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import login
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def login(request, **kwargs):
    return login(request, **kwargs)
```

Could anyone help me here?

UPDATED: Mixin class

```
class RequireStaffMixinView(RequireAuthMixinView):
    # Override 1) ensure staff
    # @method_decorator(staff_user_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.request.user.is_staff:
            raise PermissionDenied
        return super(RequireAuthMixinView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs
```

Comment: Could you post your view where there is the logic code that handle authentication with something like an `authenticate` method, please?

Comment: `user.is_authenticated` is working but the my user should be `superuser` to access the next page. Check out the `mixin` class which I am using to make sure the users are always `superuser` to access the next page or raise `Permission Denied`

Comment: What is the mixin doing in the User model?

Comment: Making sure that the user model is `superuser` otherwise raising `PermissionDenied`

Comment: Regarding login functionality I am using the `from django.contrib.auth.views import login`

Comment: What does your login view responds with when it doesn't allow you to authenticate with your portal.User superuser's credentials?

Comment: It is able to authenticate but superuser can only view next page. It is not able to recognize the superuser part, and giving me a response of permission denied. My users are superuser as you can see in the figure as well.

Comment: See the mixin class which I have updated. If the user is not superuser, then it will raise Permission Denied

Comment: Do you mean to return `super(RequireAuthMixinView)` or should that be `RequireStaffMixinView`?  May be nothing....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a custom user model, extend the AbstractBaseUser model as recommended by django docs and add your custom fields to it.

Also note that due to limitations of Django’s dynamic dependency feature for swappable models, you must ensure that the model referenced by AUTH_USER_MODEL is created in the first migration of its app (usually called 0001_initial); otherwise, you will have dependency issues.

models.py

```
import uuid

from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
from django.db import models


class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password, **kwargs):
        if not email or not password:
            raise ValueError('User must have a username and password')

        user = self.model(
            email=CustomUserManager.normalize_email(email),
            **kwargs
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()

        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **kwargs):
        user = self.create_user(email, password, **kwargs)

        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.save()

        return user


class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    email = models.EmailField(null=False, unique=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    # Add custom fields here
    api_token = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    token_created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name']

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.first_name + " " + self.last_name

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.first_name

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_staff

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return self.is_staff

    def api_token_reset(self):
        self.api_token = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created_on',)
        db_table = 'users'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.get_full_name()
```

And add the following code to your settings.py. NOTE- tester is the name of my app

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'tester.User'
```

Now run the following commands -

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Now you should be able to login to the django admin without any problems.

If you want to create a custom login page, in the view check if the user is an admin or not -

views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.views.generic import FormView


class LoginView(FormView):
    form_class = AuthenticationForm
    template_name = 'login.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        username = form.cleaned_data['username']
        password = form.cleaned_data['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        # Check here if the user is an admin
        if user is not None and user.is_active and user.is_staff:
            login(self.request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(self.success_url)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)
```

login.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post">
    {%  csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from .views import LoginView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login/$', LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
]
```

Comment: Thanks @Utkarsh for such a elaborated answer. I will look into this and accept.

Comment: I am traveling right now so couldn't get time to look the issue again. I gave you 50 points though :) your answer is definitely very helpful

Answer (score -1):

Dont know how but i added is_active ,is_admin, is_staff ,is_superuser as true is the super user creation function changed is_active to true in create user and added the above specified backends in settings.py  and it started working you just have to creat a new superuser and new database with new migrations after all these alterations. it should work...

create superuser function :

```html
 def create_superuser(self,email, user_name, address, password, **other_fields):
        user = self.creat_user(email,user_name,address ,password=password,**other_fields)
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_active = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save()

        return user
```

create user function

```html
class NewUser(AbstractBaseUser,PermissionsMixin):
    alphanumeric = RegexValidator(r'^[0-9a-zA-Z]*$', message='Only alphanumeric characters are allowed.') 
    email = models.EmailField(_('Enter Email'),unique=True)
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True, validators=[alphanumeric])
    address= models.TextField(_(
        'enter Address'),max_length=500,blank=True)

    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    objects =CustomeAccountManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['user_name','address']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```