# Substitute auth_user model not authenticating properly (Django)

Tags: django, django-models, django-authentication

Hello everyone I started working on a Django app for a class project but I am running into some confusion when trying to authenticate custom users.

The app is a social media platform for my school and as per the requirements of the project I must attach a biography and a role (position at the school). I figured the best way to do this is to attach it to the existing auth_user model but upon following almost all the content I could find users wont authenticate.

Even when supplied the correct information the user object is still None.

To start off lets take a look at my user model which is declared in an app called "landingpage"

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    bio=models.TextField()
    role=models.CharField(max_length=32)
```

Then we go to the main app and declare which AUTH_USER_MODEL we want

```py
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "landingpage.User"
```

Finally applying the migration commands

```bash
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Then to test it out I have this code. My login system is a popup form so in order to avoid visiting the page I just redirect back to the index which also refreshes the page so I can update content based on the authenticated user. There is probably a better way to do this with javascript but I believe this is fine for now.

```py
def login(request):
    # If page is accessed via browser return because there is nothing here
    if request.method=='GET':
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    username=request.POST['username']
    password=request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

Even when a correct username & password are supplied the user object will be None.

I suspect this might be because this is my 4th migration but I dont really understand the django framework that well because its only my third day.

I have read the docs here
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model

I also found a similar stackoverflow post but it didnt solve the issue
[Not able to authenticate custom user model in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33641243/not-able-to-authenticate-custom-user-model-in-django)

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to check values passed to backend in `request.POST`, because authentication process is case-sensitive. Maybe they are lowercase, but username in DB is uppercase?

When you've validated data but still can not login, you can change user password using `python manage.py changepassword`

After you changed your password and `authenticate` returns `User` instance -
Your code is almost working

The thing is, `authenticate` just verifies that user entered correct username+password, nothing more.
So to actually login user, you need to use `login` function like this:

```py
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login

def login(request):
    # If page is accessed via browser return because there is nothing here
    if request.method=='GET':
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    username=request.POST['username']
    password=request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user:
        login(request, user)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by the order in which I created the databases.

To start off I changed the name of my custom user from User to something else but I was still extending the abstract user class.

so I set the AUTH_USER_MODEL in the root app, note that my custom user is not coming from the root app and this is important

```py
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "landingpage.HuskyBookUser"
```

then I deleted my sqlite database and the migrations folder from the landingpage app. Needless to say dont do this in production, you will have to find a more elegant solution.

Then I ran the following commands. I created my AbstractUser first with this

```bash
python manage.py makemigrations landingpage
python manage.py migrate landingpage
```

Then I migrated the rest of the app

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

After this I am returning user objects through the authenticate function that didn't work in my previous post.

I think the root of my issue is that I created the app with the default auth_users table and it never actually knew that I had another one.